# How to refresh JTable after inserting data to database?

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jtable

I'm populating JTable from access database. when running the code for the first time, table loads perfectly. Then adding new records to database from JDialog. What I was trying to do is to call `loadData()` method when JDialog is closed, but table is not updating.

This is my `loadData()` method:

```
private void loadData() {
    System.out.println("sssss");
    final String [] columnNames={"Seq", "First Name", "Last Name","Num1","Num2","Num3"};
    connectDb();

    data = new Object[rows][columns];
    int row = 0;
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            for(int col = 0 ; col<columns; col++ ){
                if(col==0)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_seq");
                if(col==1)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_fname");
                if(col==2)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_lname");
                if(col==3)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_num1");
                if(col==4)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_num2");
                if(col==5)
                    data[row][col]=rs.getString("contact_num3");


            }
            row++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            return false;
        }



     };

     table = new JTable(model);
}`
```

this how I call loadData method when closing the JDialog.

```
JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New Contact");
    mntmNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addData gui = new addData(viewData.this,rs);
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setVisible(true);
            gui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
                    loadData();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmNew);
```

My database is updated when adding the records but Jtable is not refreshed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
private void loadData() {
    ...
    table = new JTable(model); // don't re-create the table here
}
```

Don't re-create the table but update its model instead, either by setting a new table model or by clearing and re-filling the current one:

```
private void loadData() {
    ...
    table.setModel(model); 
    // Of course, table should have been initialized
    // and placed first, and only once!
}
```

See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062173/1795530) (includes SwingWorker to make database calls in a background thread), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630711/1795530) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27063490/1795530). Please have a look to those answers, there are explanations to make the point clear.

Comment: Thanks dic19. this works for me. I added `table = new JTable(model)` to constructor method and then within the constructor method, called the `loadData()` method. And my table takes some time to load. So now I am going to do same changes as your examples.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
     for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
         model.removeRow(i);
     }
 }

 setTablevalue();
```

I removed all the rows from the `JTable` and again called the `setTableValue` method to re-populate the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but maybe this will work?:

```
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    loadData();
    // Add this line:
    table.repaint();
}
```

If I understand what is going on, the underlying database is getting updated but the JTable component is not showing the updates. My guess is that you just have to call the `repaint()` method so that the JTable gets updated as well.

Comment: thank nihilon. this didn't work for me. But I am going to learn more about `repaint()` method.

Comment: No worries @broken_code, my guess was wrong. Way wrong. But that's why we are here, right? To learn!